# Using scope to move objects using the same coordinate system as the objects themselves

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

> **Summary of answers**
>
> The question has been answered by TorbjørnT. with a comment. If using scope with `xshift` it is necessary to specify the unit as `cm`. This is also working if the entire picture is later scaled. Thanks! The included code is now working as it should. -
>
> The solution provided by JLDiaz works just as well and does not requiere any units! Here  to image is moved using `shift={(x,z)}` (make sure to get all the brackets).
>
> A third possible solution has been proposed by Ignasi, again as a comment to the question. To me this approach using `pic` might be especially useful if elements need to be repeated a few times in the same image.
>
> Thanks for all the good input!

**The question**

I am trying to make an illustration for a latex document and it is going quite good. I know the code could be a lot better but for now it is good enough for me. Well, mostly.

Because the code is kind of purely written (or so I think) moving a group of objects is not all that easy. The solution I found ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/grouping-objects-and-applying-operation-to-the-group)) for this is `scope` which does work. However I am a bit unhappy with how it works.

In the code below the object is rotated by 15 degree around the point (0,0) as expected. However, the `xshift=2` does not shift the entire `scope` by `2` on the same scale shifting everything manually by `2` would have.

I know that the `axis` environment has it's own coordinate system that can be accessed via `(axis cs:10,10)`. Is there anything similar for `scope`?

Might [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123699/match-coordinate-in-two-different-scopes) be a solution that could be adapted (I could split the image - chair, table and computer - in separate parts I guess)?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.750]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
    % Temp stuff for construction only
        \draw[step=.2, lightgray, very thin] (0,0) grid ++(15.0,8.0);
        \foreach \s in {0,1,...,15.0}{
            \draw [lightgray](\s,0) -- (\s,-.1) node[below, lightgray]{\s};
        }
        \foreach \s in {0,1,...,8.0}{
            \draw [lightgray](0,\s) -- (-.1,\s) node[left, lightgray]{\s};
        }
% The Inside of the house
    \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm, rotate=15] % unit was not in original code for question!
        % Table
        \draw (11.9,0) rectangle ++(0.1,1.); % leg 1
        \draw (12.8,0) rectangle ++(0.1,1.);    % leg 2
        \draw (11.8,1.) rectangle ++(1.2,0.05); % Surface plate
        % Computer (iMac) ;-)
        \fill (12.72,1.45) circle (0.03); % The nob in the back
        \draw (12.74,1.45) .. controls (12.8,1.25) and (12.8,1.22) .. (12.8,1.06) -- (12.55,1.06); % Stand
        \draw [fill=white, rotate around={-10:(12.6,1.15)}] (12.6,1.2) rectangle ++(0.07,0.6); % the iMac
        % Chair
        \draw (11.1,0) -- ++(0.2,0.2) -- ++ (0.2,-0.2); % leg part 1
        \draw (11.3,0.2) -- ++(0,0.45); % leg part 2
        \draw (11.05,0.65) rectangle ++(0.5,0.05); % seat
        \draw (11,0.75) rectangle ++(0.05,0.5); % back support
        \draw (11.15,0.65) .. controls (10.95,0.57) and (10.95,0.75) .. (11,0.95); % connection seat - back
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Could anyone point me at a comprehensive guide to understand the different coordinate systems in `tikz`? I have not been able to find anything like that.

---

And this is the final image I meant to create. I know its not much and likely the code (the above is only part of it) could be written more efficiently but never the less I am very happy with the result.

[image: The final image]

Comment: Try `xshift=2cm`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! But why do I need to say `cm` with xshift when I don't need to do that for anything else (in my example)? Do you know of a source where I could find which unit is used where within tikz?

Comment: I don't really know, but I guess that when you write normal coordinates numbers are scaled by the default unit vectors if you don't specify a unit, but that this does not apply for `xshift`, so you have to specify a unit.

Comment: Instead of `scopes` you could also consider using `pics`. Here you have some examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151772/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170686/1952

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks for the input. It looks very promising to me. I will definitely look into it for my next project. From you first example it looks like it would be especially good if you need to reuse the same elements a couple of times in one picture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interestingly, the option `shift` accepts as parameter a pair of coordinates, which do not require units (beware of the braces around the parenthesis):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] {Foo};
\draw (1,1) circle (0.2);
\begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
 \node[draw] {Bar};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

You can use `scale`, `x`, and/or `y` options in the `tikzpicture`, as usual.